# Spring Integration Jms.outboundGateway x Firewalls

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

This below flow is working fine when the network firewall is open, but if we close it and the JMS broker cannot be reached, the timeout is not happening at all and the caller process is getting stuck. It seems the gateway timer does not start because the thread did not return... Can you suggest what's the best way to handle this unhappy scenario?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow request() {
  return IntegrationFlows.from(requestChannel)
                               .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(this.connectionFactyory)
                               .requestDestination(requestQueue)
                               .extractReplyPayload(false)
                               .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID")
                               .receiveTimeout(5000L))
                               .channel(replyChannel).get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See `receiveTimeout` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set the max timeout value for the MessageConsumer's receive call when
 * waiting for a reply. The default value is 5 seconds.
 * @param receiveTimeout The receive timeout.
 */
public void setReceiveTimeout(long receiveTimeout) {
```

So, it is really about a *reply*, which is going to be triggered when we have already sent a *request*. More over you definitely use those default 5 seconds for its value. So, the blocking problem is somewhere else.

It would be great if you share with us some DEBUG (or even TRACE) logs for `org.springframework.integration` to see what is going on when you send a message to the flow without JMS broker access.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I checked at DEBUG/TRACE level, but nothing relevant is there. I agree the requestor should timeout, but I found this scenario strange anyway. Let me know whether you need more info or have any other ideas.

Comment: You probably need to look at your JMS provider's client documentation to set a connection timeout. If the firewall just drops the SYN packet, the client will be stuck; take a thread dump to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: Gents, In order to test this scenario further, I added a MessagingGateway to trigger the mentioned integration flow pushing a message towards the requestChannel. Even setting the request/reply timeout at MessagingGateway/Gateway level (which is on the top of the integration flow) the timeout does not happen. Most probably because the main thread does not return? Using a resilient client to call the integration flow resolves and the issue won't be there. I'm wondering if adding a "task executor" in the integration flow would help. Not sure if this the way to go. Any advice?

Comment: Thing is, I'd like to handle this scenario in the integration flow itself since I have no control on the client side. Let's imagine that I have a REST API that will be exposed where the requests will trigger the integration flow.

Comment: That's not what we are talking about: the blocking problem comes from the JMS client you use when it tries to send. Even if you introduce a "task executor" into your flow, the JMS client is still going to block and eventually all your threads are going to be stuck. So, or figure out how to make that request timeout finite or consult with your vendor how to break that blocking thread to release resources of your application.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Let me investigate further.